# Calling function twice gives segfault (in connection with char* to string conversion)

Tags: c++, string, winapi, segmentation-fault, char

I want to expand a string (`"%LOCALAPPDATA%/test.txt"`) with a Windows environment path. The following function in principle does the job, but calling it again with the same output string (or assigning some value to the output string before calling the function) gives a segfault.

Obviously I am making some (probably really bad) mistake by converting `char*` to `std::string`, but I don't really understand what is going on here (beside the fact that some memory address is not available later on).

```
#include "processenv.h"

void expandWindowsString(const std::string &input, std::string &output)
{
    const char* in = input.c_str();
    char* out;
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings(in, out, 1024);
    output = out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string path;
    expandWindowsString("%LOCALAPPDATA%/test.txt", path);
    std::cout << "path is " << path << std::endl;
    //works fine so far, but if I execute the function again (with 'path') or initialising path beforehand with std::string path = "", a segfault occurs.
    expandWindowsString("%LOCALAPPDATA%/test.txt", path); // commenting out this line, makes the code work.
    std::cout << "path is " << path << "\n";
}
```

Comment: what is `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: [expandenvironmentstringsa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa)

Comment: `char* out; -> char out[1024];`

Comment: Unfortunately, you first try is also UB, but seems to works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa) explains:

> `lpDst`
>
> A pointer to a buffer that receives the result of expanding the environment variable strings in the *lpSrc* buffer.

The buffer needs to be supplied by the caller, while the code simply passes an uninitialized pointer, alongside tricking the system into believing that it points at memory with a size of 1024 bytes.

A simple fix would be:

```cpp
void expandWindowsString(const std::string &input, std::string &output)
{
    const char* in = input.c_str();
    char out[1024];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings(in, out, 1024);
    output = out;
}
```

There's lots of room for improvement, e.g.

- Using the [Unicode version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsw)
- Handling errors (as explained in the documentation)
- Repeatedly growing the output buffer in case the API call returns a value larger than the provided buffer length
- Constructing a `std::string` using the [pointer and length](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)
- Returning a value rather than using an out parameter

As for why it fails when being called a second time: That's a meaningless question. The code exhibits undefined behavior by writing through an uninitialized pointer. With that, **any** outcome is possible, including the code appearing to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

ExpandEnvironmentStrings expects a buffer already allocated. You can determine the size of the buffer if [you pass a buffer with a size too small to hold the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa#return-value), like 0.

So, here are two versions, UNICODE and ANSI, that will compute the size dynamically:

```
std::wstring expandWindowsString(const std::wstring& input)
{
    std::wstring output;
    do
    {
        auto size = ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(input.c_str(), (LPWSTR)output.c_str(), output.size());
        if (!size || size <= output.size())
            break;

        output.resize(size);
    } while (true);
    output = output.c_str();
    return output;
}

std::string expandWindowsString(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output;
    do
    {
        auto size = ExpandEnvironmentStringsA(input.c_str(), (LPSTR)output.c_str(), output.size());
        if (!size || size <= output.size())
            break;

        output.resize(size);
    } while (true);
    output = output.c_str();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Some issues that would need to be addressed: `1` Starting with C++17, [data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) returns a pointer to non-const, allowing the `const_cast` to be dropped. `2` [reserve()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) doesn't modify the `size()`. The implementation unconditionally returns an empty string. Use [resize()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) instead, followed by another `resize()` to remove the trailing NUL character.

Comment: `3` The environment is process-global state that can be changed by any thread at any time. A robust implementation would need to repeatedly call the API until it returns a value `> 0` and `<= output.size()`.

Comment: @IInspectable - For 2, I'm using MSVC, all C++ version and it seems to work fine, but I agree it's better to use resize.

Comment: Risking to come across as too pedantic, I'd still recommend the following two changes: `1` Adding another call to `resize()` to strip the trailing NUL character, that's still part of the controlled sequence of the `std::string`'s. `2` Less of a cosmetic change: When the API returns `0`, that should really be reported as an error. [std::system_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/system_error) would be a good candidate. Also, if you could copy the parts of my answer that address the question into this answer, it would make for a mighty fine Q&A.

Comment: @IInspectable - actually, the ANSI version puts two terminating zeros which is strange (this is documented). As for the error, I prefer to return an empty string than raising an error, that was by design, my personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa)

> `lpDst`
>
> A pointer to a buffer that receives the result of expanding the environment variable strings in the lpSrc buffer. Note that this buffer cannot be the same as the lpSrc buffer.

> `nSize`
>
> The maximum number of characters that can be stored in the buffer pointed to by the lpDst parameter. When using ANSI strings, the buffer size should be the string length, plus terminating null character, plus one. When using Unicode strings, the buffer size should be the string length plus the terminating null character.

You will see you pass invalid parameter, you have to provide `buffer`, so:

```
void expandWindowsString(const std::string &input, std::string &output)
{
    char out[1024];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings(input.c_str(), out, sizeof (out));
    output = out;
}
```

or avoiding output parameter:

```
std::string expandWindowsString(const std::string &input)
{
    char out[1024];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings(input.c_str(), out, sizeof (out));
    return out;
}
```

Notice that you should probably check return value of `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`.